# ASP.NET Core Open Identity Connect client. How to store given_name in claims?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET Core application which uses OpenIdConnect authentication using the following configuration:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(
        "oidc",
        o =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.GetSection("Identity").Bind(o);
            o.ClientId = "webui";
            o.ClientSecret = "****";
            o.CallbackPath = "/cb_openIdConnect";
            o.SaveTokens = true;
            o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            o.Scope.Add("email");
            o.Scope.Add("profile");
            o.UsePkce = true;
            o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("given_name", "given_name");
        });
```

The IDP server is a server I control running OpenIddict. Even though I have the `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` option enabled, I can't seem to persist claims from the userinfo endpoint into my own local token.

When I add a `OnUserInformationReceived` even, I can see that `given_name` is returned in userinfo.

```
        o.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = e =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.User.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

"{ "sub": "****", "given_name": "***", "family_name": "****" }"
```

However, `given_name` does not exist when I access the claims of the `UserPrincipal` returned by 
[AuthenticationStateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authenticationstateprovider-service).

I also tried adding a bogus value, but even this value is not visible in the claims list from within a page:

```cs
o.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = e =>
            {
                e.Principal?.AddClaim("given_name", "wef");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
```

How do I get my claims from the OIDC userinfo endpoint into the list of claims in the `HttpContext` `UserPrincipal` so I can display some of the claims on the webpage?

No matter what I try, my claims only contains the following types:

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp
```

Comment: Could you output all the claims in your ClaimsPrincipal and add that to your answer. Your code looks right - maybe you need to precede it with `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`.

Comment: @GaryArcher I updated with the list of claims I can see. No matter what I try, the claims don't change from those 4.

Answer (score 0):

The tech stack defaults to the use of older WS-Federation claim names. You need to update your code like this to use OpenID Connect claim names:

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
```

You should then get claims like `sub`, `given_name` and `email`. The exact claims you see will depend on the `scope` values configured, and possibly also on which settings are configured under the admin user interface of OpenIddict.

Comment: None of given_name or the microsoft claim names exist in the ClaimsIdentity. I updated the original post with all of the claims listed.